# Send to another controller when user is from opera mini

Tags: php, symfony

I have developed a website in Symfony2. I am using [Suncat MobileDetectBundle](https://github.com/suncat2000/MobileDetectBundle) to detect if a user is from mobile or PC. I have to create 3 separate versions for desktop, smartphones and for Java based phones. I have a DefaultController with following code

```
    public function indexAction()
    {
    $mobileDetector = $this->get('mobile_detect.mobile_detector');
    if($mobileDetector->isMobile())
    $render='AcmeUitBundle:Android:Default/';
    else
     $render='AcmeUitBundle:Default:';
    //More Code goes here
    }
```

When a user is from smartphone, It will render template present in 'Android/Default' folder and when he is from Computer,Templates from 'Default' folder are displayed.

Now I have another controller, 'JavaController' in which I will have code to display for Java based phones.

What I want to do is to check when a user is from a java based phone,Opera mini or ucweb, then execute JavaController and when user is from a smartphone or Desktop then execute DefaultController

Comment: I don't understand your question: do you need to render a different page or do you need to execute a different action? Moreover, do you need URL to change or don't you?

Comment: I need to execute different action. I have separate controllers for mobile and PC. I can check easily inside controller if user is from mobile or not but I have to check this thing before controller execution starts. URL change does not matter much but its good if user is from mobile then he gets redirected to m.sitename.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To know if the phone is android you can use :

```
extends \Mobile_Detect {}

if($this->is('AndroidOS')){
}
```

Suncat extends the mobile_detect library which have lot of kind of checks as AndroidOS check IOS etc... so you can use that.

## Edit :

I understand better now, you can either use this indexAction and detect if it is android with this code :

```
if($mobileDetector->isMobile()){
   if(mobileDetector->is('AndroidOS')){
       return $this->forward('YourBundle:Java:index'); //this is your bundle name your controller name then your action name.
    }
    $render='AcmeUitBundle:Android:Default/';
 }
 else
     $render='AcmeUitBundle:Default:';
    //More Code goes here
    }
```

Or use another action that will detect mobile and which OS then forward to whatever action controller you need either default one or java one

Comment: Yes I can check easily inside controller if user is from mobile or not but I have to check this thing before controller execution starts.  
I need to execute different action. I have separate controllers for mobile and PC.